# Copy Hyperlinks in LibreOffice

Tags: html, libreoffice

I face the problem that I need to copy a list of hyperlinks from LibreOffice Calc to an HTML file:

I created the list in LibreOffice Calc (3.3.2) with the function hyperlink(Link-Text;Link-URL). The Links work in the spreadsheets. Until now I have not found any way to copy such a Link (Link-Text not equal Link-URL) or the list of links to any other document. I tried:

- Copy/Paste Special in Office Calc
- Copy/Paste to Writer
- Upload the spreadsheet to LibreOffice Base
- Save the file as HTML
- Copy/Paste into an HTML editor.

-> only the URL-Text gets copied but never the link. I appreciate any help!

Comment: What HTML editor are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, and it worked:

1. Select the cells you want to copy (optional)
2. *File / Export*
3. File type: *XHTML*
4. Click on *Selection* checkbox (optional)
5. Choose filename and click *Save* button

The HTML file will contain both Link-Text and Link-URL

Comment: Saving the file as HTML also works

Comment: Since the original question is specifically asking about creating an HTML file. Just to be clear, **there is not easy way of copying a link without exporting to a new file?** I have a different use-case than the original question but my problem is the same. Problem: Can't copy link. Use case: Copy link into non-default browser without auto-opening page.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is another solution that uses macros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10279574). It can extract the links to another column or to another worksheet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

File type: XHTML will be the problem. Normaly if you copy the hyperlinked text from libre office to another WYSIWYG editor everything comes with CSS no problem. I tried and worked.